# How to store the data in database in chinese language on progress 4gl?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

How can store the data in database in chinese formate. When i display it should show in chinese language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you install Progress you are prompted to make decisions about character sets and code pages.  For maximum interoperability you probably want to use UTF-8 but there are several other options that also support Chinese.

If Progress has already been installed the -cp* startup parameters tell you which code page is in use.  You can find the default global settings in $DLC/startup.pf (or %DLC%\startup.pf if you are running Windows).  Or you can look at the db startup section of the .lg file -- the startup parameters actually used are shown immediately following a (333) message.

If your database already exists and is not using a compatible code page you can convert it with "proutil -C convchar" but that can be a complex project and you need a very thorough understanding of all of the application's input and output sources before you do that.

It is very important that the database and any clients connecting to it all agree on which code pages are in use and that any differences are compatible with each other.  You should not, for instance, start a client with UTF-8 and write Chinese characters into a database that is expecting iso-8859.